# 2003 cts cadillac 3.2

Tags: gasket, cadillac, cts, intake

2 cts cadillac. On the top of the air intake manifold runs a black strip. Underneath that black strip my gasket or O ring has broke. I don't know the name of it and have gone to several automotive stores and they don't either. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Go to a decent store and they will come out and look at the parts or even take them in with you.

Comment: can you take picture of it? I mean the part, not the car :)

Comment: A Cadillac dealer, or someone with access to the parts book for that model, could be of help.